# Collapsed Navbar - Rails 4 CSS align right

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a custom navbar where I have spaced out the links through the use of seperate divs for each of the links.  When the width is < 768px the collapsed links are spaced very irregularly and I'd like to correct this CSS while maintaining the CSS for the un-collapsed version.

### HTML

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <%= link_to("Brand Name", root_path, { :class => "navbar-brand logo" }) %>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav middle-left">
          <li><%= link_to("About", about_path, { :class => "nav-link-custom" }) %></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav middle-right">
          <li><%= link_to("Help", help_path, { :class => "nav-link-custom" }) %></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="nav-link-custom" href="#">Sign In</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<%= yield %>

</body>
```

### CSS

```
/* Navbar */

.logo:hover {
  background: none;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  background: none;
}

.middle-left {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.middle-right {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background: white;
  border: thin solid gray;
}


.icon-bar {
  background: gray;
}
```

### Un-Collapsed

[image: Uncollapsed navbar]

^ I took this screenshot because I couldn't get the fiddle to work.

### Collapsed

[image: Collapsed navbar]

^ I took this screenshot because I couldn't get the fiddle to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a media query and your nav will result in the default mobile nav.

```css
/* Navbar */

.navbar .logo:hover {
  background: none;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
  background: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  background: white;
  border: thin solid gray;
}
.navbar .icon-bar {
  background: gray;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .middle-left {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .navbar .middle-right {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav middle-left">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav middle-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="nav-link-custom" href="#">Sign In</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works great, still working on my use of media queries

Comment: Modifying that Ruby on Rails code to HTML requires much patience. +1 for that :D

Comment: No problem and you're welcome and thanks @manoj-kumar, only a few lines! :>

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `margin` CSS inside a media query so that it will effect the text only in expanded version.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .middle-left {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }

  .middle-right {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}
```